# EDIT: How do you make a container fill the width of bootstrap col class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and hover.css to create a list-group where the list-group-items are buttons. The problem is that I can't set the width of these items to only fill the space of their parent.

EDIT: The problem was not actually that the buttons were going outside the container. It's the containers that are going outside the columns

In my html I currently have:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="list-box">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Some title</h1>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item hvr-sweep-to-left" ng-repeat="project in currentUser.projects">
                        {{Something}}
                    </button>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my css I currently have:

```
.list-box 
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #000000;
    display: block;
}

.list-group-item
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is the hover.css I am using

```
/* Button Effect - Sweep To Left */
.hvr-sweep-to-left {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #4393b9;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-left:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-left:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-left:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-left:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/* Button Effect - Sweep To Right */
.hvr-sweep-to-right {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #4393b9;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-right:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-right:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/* Back Pulse */
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-back-pulse {
  50% {
    background-color: rgba(32, 152, 209, 0.75);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-back-pulse {
  50% {
    background-color: rgba(32, 152, 209, 0.75);
  }
}

.hvr-back-pulse {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
}
.hvr-back-pulse:hover, .hvr-back-pulse:focus, .hvr-back-pulse:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-back-pulse;
  animation-name: hvr-back-pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-color: #2098d1;
  background-color: #2098d1;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: first, change list-box to list-group.... can you post whats in hover.css

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vawicepece/edit?html,css,output

Comment: or something more like this ? http://jsbin.com/qewogotelo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks for replying, the first style you showed me was closer to what I was going for, but for some reason my buttons that are listed still fly outside of their containers.

Comment: can you post a link to your site?

Comment: Sorry the site is just running on a local host right now. From some google searches I have some slight suspicions that problems may be caused from the absolute position setting found in the hover.css

Comment: Thank you again Rachel for the help! I

Comment: Hi sorry i actually tried. It's saying my reputation isn't high enough to do that. Or did you mean select the checkmark?

Comment: yeah just the check mark :), thanks. when you have 15 rep you can up-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the bg color to red just to check the size/fitting. Jsbin link [here](http://output.jsbin.com/vawicepece/) What you're after or no?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: #000000;
  display: block;
}
h1 {
  font-size: large;
}
.list-group-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Some title</h1>
      <div class="list-group">
        <button type="button" class="list-group-item hvr-sweep-to-left" ng-repeat="project in currentUser.projects">
          {{Something}}
        </button>
        <li class="list-group-item">Coffee</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Tea</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Milk</li>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi I actually think I replied in the wrong place. My buttons still seem to somehow fly outside of the container. Im going to edit my original post with the css I've borrowed from hover.css.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. However here is the solution if you want the list items to fill their parent:

```
body{width:100%;}
.container 
{    background-color: red;
    border-color: #000000;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
h1{font-size:large;}
.list-group-item
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This solution is actually similar to the one Rachel Gallen is suggesting, but my buttons still seem to be flying off the screen.